# Change my profile's PATH environment variable on Cygwin

Tags: path, cygwin

Sadly, I am not at all experienced in coding. I am attempting to use a program to work with GRIB files, here: http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/degrib/compile.php?os=windows. I am compiling as there are ample bugs down the road with the install package.

I've installed Cygqin and MinGW. Now I am trying to insert MinGW into the environment path of my Cygwin user, as instructed in the MinGW documentation about halfway down the page here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ ("using MinGW with Cygwin"). Problem is, I just can't figure out the commands to do this. I know this is simple, but I've today is the 3rd day I've been stuck on this. Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: Where's your MingW installation located? What is your current `PATH`?

Comment: whats the command to list the user path? MinGW is currently set to C:/MingW

Comment: That would be `echo "$PATH"`.

Answer (score 3):

To add MingW to your Cygwin `PATH`, edit your `.profile` and add:

```
export PATH="/cygdrive/c/mingw/bin:$PATH"
```

Since `C:` is already mounted by Cygwin, you don't need to worry about that, and can simply use the mount path.